# Is it possible to move from delicious.com to Evernote?

Tags: delicious, evernote

Is it possible to move all links from my delicious.com bookmarks to Evernote?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Evernote you can import all your delicious bookmarks, maybe this can help you...

Answer (score 3):

I tried this and it worked perfectly:

[Import Delicious Bookmarks to Evernote](http://dr-palaniraja.blogspot.com/2010/12/import-delicious-bookmarks-to-evernote.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can even use both: delicious and evernote, if you do not want to leave delicious behind.

Use the new ifttt.com (if this than that) to create a simple trigger to add delicious links to evernote.

http://deepenvalley.blogspot.com/2011/02/delicious-and-evernote-synchronisation.html

Its pretty cool. I am wondering what ifttt will be useful for in the future...

Answer (score 0):

Evernote used to offer this functionality, but they've since [discontinued it](https://support.evernote.com/link/portal/16051/16058/Article/2516/Can-I-import-my-Delicious-com-bookmarks-into-Evernote).

A third-party web application, [Delicious to Evernote](http://delicioustoevernote.rodrigojuarez.com.ar/), now offers this functionality, but only imports 1000 bookmarks and sometimes errors with "Error processing : Exception of type 'Evernote.EDAM.Error.EDAMUserException' was thrown." Also note that you need to trust this developer with your private information to use it.

Someone else offered [instructions on how to do this manually](http://dr-palaniraja.blogspot.com/2010/12/import-delicious-bookmarks-to-evernote.html) using the Delicious API to export, a JavaScript-based translator, and the Evernote desktop app's import feature, but not everyone has been able to make this solution work for them.

For new bookmarks, it is possible to [replicate them on Evernote using ifttt.com](http://ifttt.com/recipes/search?q=delicious%20evernote).